# In-app purchase multiple products

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Can we make multiple inapp purchase products as a single product (with price of all and to unlock all features) in inapp purchase
 or should we send product identifiers of individual products and unlock each feature individually??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple inApp for each functionnality or a single inApp to unlock all functionnalities.
You are free to unlock what functionnalities with your inApp.

Comment: What about hosted in-app purchases? How can we download each product?

Comment: Is it possible to unlock all the other in app purchases with one of another in app purchases, so if they try to buy one of the other they are counted as "owned" already?